# How to number each element of a list to form a table of points?

Tags: code-review

Suppose we have a list given below

```
OurList={a,b,c,d,e}
```

Is there a way to attribute a number to each element of OurList so that we could form a table of points? The expected result is

```
OutTable={{1,a},{2,b},{3,c},{4,d},{5,e}}
```

Comment: `Transpose[{Range[1, Length@ourList], ourList}]`. Please do not start variable names with uppercase characters. OR `Thread[{Range[1, Length@#], #}] &@ourList`

Comment: Look at [`List Manipulation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListManipulation.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are may be 10 others ways to do this, but this is good problem for using `MapIndexed`

```
lis = {a, b, c, d, e}
MapIndexed[{First[#2], #1} &, lis]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
MapIndexed[{2*First[#2], #1} &, lis]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Does this method generalise to using a formula instead of 1,2,3,4... to label each element of a list in order? For example I might want {{2,a},{4,b}...} instead so the numbering formula is for nth element of a list, the corresponding number should be 2t instead of t, is there a way your method could be extended to include this scenario?

Comment: @Rescy_ updated.